# Class design query

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface `Schema`, and another called `SchemaParser`. 
`SimpleSchemaParser` implements `SchemaParser` and `SimpleSchema` implements `Schema`.

`SimpleSchemaParser` has a method `parseSchema()` which returns a `Schema`. This way, `SimpleSchemaParser.parseSchema()` would return a `Schema` object. But I know that `SimpleSchemaParser` would always return a `SimpleSchema`. How should I change my design to make this apparent, rather than always having to cast the result to `SimpleSchema`? Should I go for generics in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use generics, but they're not required:

```
class SchemaExample 
{
    interface Schema 
    {
        // methods go here
    }

    interface SchemaParser 
    {
        Schema parseSchema();
    }

    class SimpleSchema implements Schema 
    {
        // implementation of Schema's methods
    }

    class SimpleSchemaParser implements SchemaParser 
    {
        @Override
        public SimpleSchema parseSchema() 
        {
            // real business logic here...
            return new SimpleSchema();
        }   
    }

    void usage() 
    {
        SimpleSchema schema = new SimpleSchemaParser().parseSchema();
    }
}
```

A slightly broader question is: *why do you care which implementation of schema is returned?* Are there methods that only exist on `SimpleSchema`? Can these move up to the interface `Schema`?

Comment: +1 for asking why. The use of a covariant return isn't necessarily helpful, because it only kicks in if the parser is held in a variable of type `SimpleSchemaParser` rather than `SchemaParser`. A generics-based approach would let you get a `SimpleSchema` even from a `SchemaParser` (because it would be a `SchemaParser<SimpleSchema>`). But yeah, why?

Comment: Covariance return type is one the most important feature in java5. It's sometimes very convenient to use this construct and in this case it is. Generics are not well designed in this case because there is a new object to construct (it will certainly lead to Class.newInstance or worst java.lang.reflect).

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I thought I had tried this.. covariant return types are great. To answer your question, yes, I have different `SchemaParsers`, can each one can return a different `Schema`. Different in the sense they have additional features.. Let me know if I should be going about this in some other way

Answer (score 3):

Since java 5 you are allowed to return SimpleSchema. This is called "covariant return-type overriding".

So Just write

```
class SimpleSchemaParser implements SchemaParser {
  @Override
  public SimpleSchema parseSchema() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The current approach is right. It encourages the interface-oriented programming: the program should always work with the entities SchemaParser and Schema, and not to be worried about if it is based on a SimpleSchema or other type. If the interfaces are well-designed, the cast shouldn't be necessary: the interface methods are the only ones that should be used/called latter.

```
SchemaParser parser = new SimpleSchemaParser()
Schema schema = parser.parseSchema()
```